# Google Chart - different backgrounds depends on x axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I use google chart and on x axis I have days of week and on y axis some values. I want to change background for weekends. It is possible in google charts?

I mark on screen field that should have different color:

[image]

Comment: I am afraid the Google Visualization API does not have an option to do this. You may be able to put a colored, semi-transparent div over the section you want colored, but if that section moves at all you may have some trouble putting the div in the right place.

Comment: Would something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/KJavc/) work for you?

Comment: @asgallant it exactly what I need. But I missing something. Where are you set backgrounds colors? Or is automatic provide by google chart?

Comment: Set the colors in the `series` option.  Each element in the `series` array can take a `color` option, which takes an RGB color string, eg `'#f357aa'`.